# Multiplying a dataframe by a column... but values are strings?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that includes binary variables about respondents' behavior and the weight associated with each respondent.  I'd like to multiply the scores by each respondents' weight so I can easily get a weighted average for the total behavior.

The easiest thing would be to multiply the weight column against another column in a loop, as in `df.columns[761]*df.columns[i]`.  However, when I try to do, it throws an error of:

> 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'.'

I shouldn't have any strings, but in the off-chance there are, I tried to convert the `df` to numeric, like so `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`.

But the problem still remains.  I'm at my wits' end.  Is there a workaround?  Should I go row by row (and if so, do I need to loop through every column, or is there a nice clean way?).

Comment: Do you know for which rows/values this method is failing? If so, could you post what they are?

Comment: One of many downsides to not giving a [mcve] is that it's hard to know whether you actually did what you said you did.  For example, it sounds like you want to multiply two columns, but `df.columns[761]*df.columns[i]` doesn't do that -- it tries to multiply two *names* of columns.  Please edit to include a working (that is, a _failing_) example.

Comment: Thanks--that actually was indeed my problem.  Duly noted :)

Answer (score 2):

You could always break apart your dataframe.

```
for col in df.columns:
    for index, k in enumerate(df[col]):
        try:
            float(k)
        except:
            # Print out the row number, col and row value that's failing
            print(index, col, k)
```

It's entirely possible you've got strings/none-types that are causing your multiplication.

There's also `df[col].apply(float)` but it won't catch those errant rows.

Comment: Thanks--this is a good solution, but unfortunately, it didn't shore up any errant rows.